# Two linear maps which commute

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If $S$ and $T$ are linear maps over a finite dimensional complex vector space. They commute i.e $ST=TS$. Is there any common subspace under which both are invariant ?

I guess it is $\mathrm{span}(v)$ where $v$ is an eigenvector of one of $S$ or $T$. Am I correct ? But I am stuck in proving it.

What is the significance of $ST=TS$ here ?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Suppose that $v$ is an eigenvector for $T$. Can you show that $Sv$ is an eigenvector for $T$, with the same eigenvalue?

Comment: yes i got the solution.

Comment: prasenjit, I see that you are not in the practice of accepting answers to many of your questions on MSE. It is a sign of courtesy towards people who have offered their help. I recommend you go back and accept answers to your past questions.